# Automatically transfer logs from keycloak database to syslog

Tags: database, events, keycloak, syslog, keycloak-services

I know that Keycloak saves all its "login events" on the server in the "Events" tab, but also in the database (I came across lines referring to KeycloakDS and Keycloak Database in standalone.xml). Hence my question - since login events are saved in the database, is there any way to automatically save them directly to Syslog? Is there any automaton which copies data from the database and saves it in Syslog? I've heard about various extensions for Keycloak (MQTT, RabbitMQ, or various event-listeners), but I don't know if they can be used for direct automatic copying of data from the Keycloak database to Syslog. Does anyone perhaps have any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement custom EventListener that will transfer all events to Syslog.

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_events

In your implementation you could use syslog appender (You can configute it at JBoss/wildfly level, see logging coniguration in standalone.xml).

Comment: Thank you so much! I have one question, what is a "syslog appender" because I haven't found much information about it (searching I only found information about log4j)

Comment: Take a look here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400263/jboss-as-7-configure-logging-to-syslog-appender
https://docs.wildfly.org/19/wildscribe/subsystem/logging/syslog-handler/index.html

Answer (score 0):

More recent versions already log to the [console by default](https://www.keycloak.org/server/logging), and if using systemd this traverses over to journald and can be picked up by rsyslogd or similar as well.

All that's needed to get login events is to modify the log level so that INFO level messages land in the logging handler.  Unfortunately [this info](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#event-listener) isn't up front in the configuration or logging pages.

`bin/kc.[sh|bat] start --spi-events-listener-jboss-logging-success-level=info --spi-events-listener-jboss-logging-error-level=info`